# How do I open specific activities when selecting from an array in a navigation drawer?

Tags: android, arrays, android-intent, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I'm trying to figure out the right way to implement this feature into this algorithm. I would like to be able to open a specific activity for "Log History", "New Log", "Analytics", "Settings".

```
private void addDrawerItems() {
    String[] osArray = { "Log History", "New Log", "Analytics", "Settings"};
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, osArray);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewLogActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you never change your array,

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    switch (position) {
    case 0: //Log History
        startActivity(this, LogHistory.class);
        break;
    case 1: //Log History
        startActivity(this, NewLog.class);
        break;
    case 2: //Log History
        startActivity(this, Analytics.class);
        break;
    case 3: //Log History
        startActivity(this, Settings.class);
        break;
    default:
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("wtf, unknown position");
    }
}
```

I can't remember if position starts at 0 or 1, but it should give you an idea of what to do.

Comment: I woke up this morning to notice I left out the new Intent deceleration necessary inside the startActivity, but you get the idea of how it works.